# Auto create hang out links

Tags: asp.net-mvc, google-calendar-api

I am working on an application. We have successfully implemented "Google.Apis.Calendar.v3". Events are created and showing in calendar. But while creating the event I want to add functionality to auto create hangout link which i can use and send to customers. I want to ask is it possible to do it through "Google.Apis.Calendar.v3.Data". If yes, how I can implement. I will really appreciate your help.

Regards,

Comment: you need to add conferenceData to your event [create events conferencing](https://developers.google.com/calendar/create-events#conferencing)

Answer (score 0):

When making the request to create the event using [insert](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/insert) or modifying an event using [patch](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/patch), you simply need to:

1. Set the `conferenceDataVersion` parameter equal one (1).
2. In the body add the option to **"createRequest"** and a "requestId" in the body as part of the "conferenceData" option like:

```js
{
  "end": {
    "dateTime": "2020-07-29T09:00:00-07:00",
    "timeZone": "America/Los_Angeles"
  },
  "start": {
    "dateTime": "2020-07-28T09:00:00-07:00",
    "timeZone": "America/Los_Angeles"
  },
  "conferenceData": {
    "createRequest": {
      "requestId": "<for-you-to-decide>"
    }
  }
}
```

---

#### Note:

Keep in mind the conferences are created asynchronously, but you can always check the status of your request to let your users know what’s happening. The immediate response to this call might not yet contain the fully-populated `conferenceData` which is indicated by `status` pending.

---

You can read about it [here](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/application-development/hangouts-meet-now-available-in-google) or in the [Documentation](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events)

Comment: Hi Aerials
Thanks for the reply. But I would like to ask I am just using a google celander API and I have not G suite account. This function still  works there and how as I did not found anything regarding "conferenceData" in my api.

Comment: Google.Apis.Calendar.v3.Data. This is the api used in our application. I am actually quite new to this. I have not developed it I am working in updating the system to enable auto create hangout links